# Error with Navigate to Homescreen on React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

Hello Im getting this error when finally Logging in to my app I’m developing using React Native and Firebase. [image]

And this is some relevant code where i think I’m getting the error from. It happens when I press Login

```
const onLoginPress = () => {
    firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((response) => {
            const uid = response.user.uid
            const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
            usersRef
                .doc(uid)
                .get()
                .then(firestoreDocument => {
                    if (!firestoreDocument.exists) {
                        alert("User does not exist anymore.")
                        return;
                    }
                    const user = firestoreDocument.data()
                    navigation.navigate('Loans', {user})
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    alert(error)
                });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert(error)
        })
}
```

**EDIT 2**

This is code for my stack navigator in App.js

```
if (!global.btoa){global.btoa=encode}
if(!global.atob){global.atob=decode}

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading]=useState(true)
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        { user ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="Loans" >
            {props => <Loans {...props} extraData={user} />}
          </Stack.Screen>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen 
            name="Login" 
            options={{
              headerStyle:{backgroundColor:'#060320',},
              headerTintColor: 'white',
              headerTitleStyle: {fontWeight: 'bold',}
            }}
            component={Login} 
            />
            <Stack.Screen name="Signup" 
            options={{
              headerStyle:{backgroundColor:'#060320',},
              headerTintColor: 'white',
              headerTitleStyle: {fontWeight: 'bold',}
            }}
            component={Signup} />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

and heres the structure of my code
[image]

Comment: check your navigation, is there a screen which is called Loans?

Comment: The issue is whether or not there is a loans screen. This line `navigation.navigate('Loans', {user})` is what triggers the issue. Make sure there's a screen named "Loan" in your stack. Can you post your stack code (maybe in App.js or Navigation folder)

Comment: Yes Ill post that rn. Sorry for the long wait

Comment: @skorp there is, i posted the code and structure

Comment: @RossHochwert I posed it, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, I think your problem is related to `user` value in `App` component. If `user` is null, `Loans` screen will be not placed in your navigator stack. When you call `onLoginPress` you have to set `user` in `App` component, then navigate into `Loans` page. How to do that? There are several solutions. You could use [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) to manage your global state. Take a look, could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are conditionally rendering the Loans screen only when the `user` variable is truthy (the variable declared in `const [user, setUser] = useState(null)`).

From the code you provided it looks like you are not setting that value once the firebase log in occurs.

You would need to call `setUser(firebaseUser)` after the user logs in.

You need to do this before navigating to the screen, otherwise the "Loans" screen won't be mounted and react-navigation won't have that screen registered as part of the app.

Since you need to access the `user` value from many places in the app you should probably store it in [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or in some place you can access it when needed (like a Redux store **if** your app needs it).

Comment: should I call setUser(firebaseUser)  in my Login.js file? since that's the file that holds my onLoginPress function.